# Can you sync to the millisecond with the YouTube API when playing a video to overlay animation?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Any ideas?  Can you sync to the millisecond with the YouTube API when playing a video to overlay animation?

Comment: @Shyamal_Chandra I don't think you can by the MILLISECOND because videos with poor framerates cannot do that without conversion to 60FPS+.

Comment: What about sync at 24, 30, or 60 Hz depending on the video frame rate quality? @EgMusic

Comment: @Shyamal_Chandra That might work. Try 24HZ first, then work your way up to the highest. Also, try different formats and framerates/qualities.

Comment: also, if you ever need to DOWNLOAD videos from youtube, use savefrom.net, or just take a youtube video link, and add ss between www. and youtube.com. this will allow you to download these videos in a variety of formats.

Comment: I. E. `https://www.ssyoutube.com/watch?v=sVBQbqVxYcA  `                      (My video :3)